# Using CONCAT in a MySQL query from .NET

Tags: c#, mysql, concatenation

I am writing a C# WPF application with controls bound to a MySQL 5.5 database. I'm populating a `DataTable` using a `MySqlDataAdapter`, passing in a MySQL SELECT query.

When the query is something trivial, like `SELECT * FROM People` or `SELECT LastName, FirstName, PersonID FROM People`, all is well and my `ListBox` control ends up populated with the expected names.

When the query contains a fairly simple `CONCAT` operator, though, the query silently fails and the `ListBox` stays empty. In particular neither of the following have worked, even though both work fine from within the MySQL command line.

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(LastName, FirstName) as Name FROM People
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(LastName, FirstName) AS CHAR) as Name FROM People
```

Both `LastName` and `FirstName` are defined as `VARCHAR`. So, I wouldn't expect this to be an instance of `CONCAT` returning a binary string in any case. I mention that because it appears to have been the problem for similar issues that other folks have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd imagine the DataAdapter attempts to parse your query into an internal format so that it can do things like generate Update and Insert commands.

Can you fill your datatable using a `MySqlDataReader` instead? This is probably only helpful if you are not planning to do database updates with the `DataTable`

Going from memory...

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);
```

Comment: Yep, that worked.  Just a note that the connection must be explicitly opened before calling ExecuteReader though (unlike the data adapter).